# This simple HTML and CSS code does not only work on IOS devices

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why this code works both on the Web and on all computer browers. But on IOS devices the visualization is completely different.

html

```
  <div class="custom-column-thumbnail mt--100 mt_md--5 mt_sm--5 bg_image--38">
       <div class="bkseparator--600"></div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.mt--100 {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.mt_md--5 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.mt_sm--5 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.bg_image--38 {
    background-image: url(portfolio/pic.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.bkseparator--600 {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " on IOS devices the visualization is completely different"?  Can you provide screenshots to show what differences you are seeing?  Also let us know what you would expect to see.

Comment: where are the media queries ?

Answer (score 0):

By IOS devices do you mean mobile devices? Smaller screens will adjust the look of a web page. You might need to build in some [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) and develop each page with smaller screen sizes in mind.